# How to read and write bits to a byte array

Tags: c++, c, class, buffer, bit

I have a **unsigned char** buffer, and I'm wondering how I would write and read signed and unsigned bits to this byte buffer.

In the **Source Engine** there is a class named **bf_write**, which two main methods (used by WriteString, WriteChar, WriteLong, etc.) use two functions named **WriteUBitLong** and **WriteSBitLong**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "signed and unsigned bits". There's no such thing as a signed or unsigned bit. It's either 0 or 1.

Comment: Can you provide some code sample for what you want to do?

Comment: How can a bit be signed or unsigned? It can either be 0 or 1.

Comment: Do you mean write a singed/unsigned variable of N bits?

Comment: sign+magnitude, +0 or -0

Comment: I don't know what I mean by **signed** or **unsigned** bits, but that's how it's used in the Source Engine. How would I write a character (ASCII char) using a "write single bit" function, likewise with long, short, etc.

Comment: In addition, I want to stay away from using STL (i.e. bitsets)

Comment: ANOTHER NOTE, will be in little-endian, however will be transferred across a network, but read in little-endian at the other end.

Comment: For reference, this turned up on google: http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid9CB448CBFF6A6F28199A9CC360AEEB411FC0B658.aspx?s=mdef%3Amd5#L158

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the number of bits is a compile-time constant:

```
#include <bitset>
...
std::bitset<100> b;
b[2]=true;
```

If it's not, use [Boost.dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html)

Or, if you're desperate, std::vector, which is indeed a packed bit vector:

```
#include <vector>
...
std::vector<bool> b(100);
b[2]=true;
```

You seem to want to use a library that requires bit vectors packed in an array of bytes.  Without knowing exactly what order it places the bits in, I can only note that:

1) all of the above will probably use at least 32-bit ints with bits ordered least->most or most->least significant

2) on little endian (Intel/AMD) CPUs, this means that the memory occupied by the bytes an array of ints may not be consistent with the ordering of bits within the int.  if it's "bit 0 is the lsb of int 0, ... bit 32 is the lsb of int 1, ..." then that's the same in little endian as "bit 0 is the lsb of char 0, ... bit 32 is the lsb of char 4 ...", in which case you can just cast a pointer to the int array to a pointer to char array

3) supposing the native order of bytes in your bit set / vector isn't exactly what the library needs, then you have to either have to create your own that has the layout they want, or transcribe a copy into their layout.

a) if the order of bits within a byte is different, a 256 entry lookup table giving the byte with bits reversed would be efficient.  you could generate the table with a small routine.

b) to reverse bytes from little<->big endian:

```
inline void endian_swap(unsigned short& x)
{
    x = (x>>8) | 
        (x<<8);
}

inline void endian_swap(unsigned int& x)
{
    x = (x>>24) | 
        ((x<<8) & 0x00FF0000) |
        ((x>>8) & 0x0000FF00) |
        (x<<24);
}    

inline void endian_swap(unsigned long long& x)
{
    x = (x>>56) | 
        ((x<<40) & 0x00FF000000000000) |
        ((x<<24) & 0x0000FF0000000000) |
        ((x<<8)  & 0x000000FF00000000) |
        ((x>>8)  & 0x00000000FF000000) |
        ((x>>24) & 0x0000000000FF0000) |
        ((x>>40) & 0x000000000000FF00) |
        (x<<56);
}
```

To get/set a particular bit within a word, with bit #0 in the least significant bit of word 0:

```
typedef unsigned char block_t;
const unsigned block_bits=8;

inline void set_bit(block_t *d,unsigned i) {
  unsigned b=i/block_bits;
  unsigned bit=i-(block_bits*b); // same as i%b
  block_t &bl=d[b];
  bl|=(1<<bit); // or bit with 1 (others anded w/ 0)
}

inline void clear_bit(block_t *d,unsigned i) {
  unsigned b=i/block_bits;
  unsigned bit=i-(block_bits*b); // same as i%b
  block_t &bl=d[b];
  bl&=(~(1<<bit)); // and bit with 0 (other bits anded w/ 1)
}

inline void modify_bit(block_t *d,unsigned i,bool val) {
  if (val) set_bit(d,i) else clear_bit(d,i);
}

inline bool get_bit(block_t const* d,unsigned i) {
  unsigned b=i/block_bits;
  unsigned bit=i-(block_bits*b); // same as i%b
  return d[b]&(1<<bit);
}
```

Obviously if the rule for bit organization differs, you have to change the above.

Using the widest possible int your CPU processes efficiently as block_t is best (dont' forget to change `block_bits`), unless the endianness doesn't work out w/ the library you're using.

Comment: Thanks so much! That's brilliant (would +1 but need 15 rep).

If you don't mind, please would you tell me how I would write a short and or character using your set_bit functions (don't waste time padding, I know how to do that :))

Answer (score 1):

I think a few macros are enough:

```
#define set_bit0(buf, i) ((buf)[(i)/8]&=~(1u<<(i)%8))
#define set_bit1(buf, i) ((buf)[(i)/8]|=1<<(i)%8)
#define get_bit(buf, i) ((buf)[(i)/8]>>(i)%8&1)
```

In addition, swapping endianness can be done in a faster way. For example, for a 64-bit integer v, the following operations swap its endianness:

```
v = ((v & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFLLU) << 32) | (v >> 32);
v = ((v & 0x0000FFFF0000FFFFLLU) << 16) | ((v & 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000LLU) >> 16);
v = ((v & 0x00FF00FF00FF00FFLLU) << 8) | ((v & 0xFF00FF00FF00FF00LLU) >> 8);
```